# How to add Images using class in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I used Some code to view the image using css..

//style.css

```
.image_link{
 background: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/images.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
 width:291;
 height:182;
}
```

I called it in post editor like,

```
<img class="image_link" alt="wp" />
```

But its not working.. Can anyone help me...

[image]

See the first place(wordpress) there is no image appear here..
another contents are all i used directly given the image url in post editor of wordpress so only its appearing than wordpress content... Can you please solve this issue..

[image]

If i go inspect element like that its displaying..

[image]

Can you see now??

Whatever u sent in comment i added in my style.css file..
Still that image is not displaying..

Comment: If you are comfortable with "Developer Tools" built-in with Chrome And FireFox, then use the element inspector to check whether the background is not being overridden.
Can you post a screenshot of that?

Answer (score -1):

Please use inline CSS.

```
<img style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/imagedirectory)"/>
```

Comment: Is there any way to call image from css using class or id??

Comment: Its ok Thank you Imran for responding me.. I use it directly via post editor of wordpress

Comment: Welcome Preethi :)

Comment: What does your developer tool show? Is there any CSS rule being overrridden?
To launch developer tools Right click at the item you wish to inspect (the first item WordPress in your case), and select "Inspect Element) . Send a screenshot of what you see there.

Comment: That screeshot is not displaying much information. Can you drag the console window a bit higher and then send the screenshot. Also, scroll the CSS rule section in the console, a bit downwards, so that we can have a look at what other rules are being applied. 

One more thing. In your CSS you have specified width as `width:291` This is wrong. It should be `width:291px;` . Same goes for height.

Probably you would need to clear the browser cache for the CSS to take effect.

Comment: Just for testing you could also try adding this rule. THis would override all other CSS rules due to higher specificity.:

`.entry-content a img.image_link{
 background: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/images.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
 width:291px;
 height:182px;
}`

Comment: @preethi. I was away for a while. hence the delay in replying. 
The screenshot you've attached now is scrolled too low. Also this does not look like the CSS for image_link element is being displayed in the screenshot.


Can you try this:
In the firebug window, in the left tab select the element `<img class="image_link"/> ` and from the right tab , select the entire CSS and paste it here or pastebin.com

Also, did you try to clear the browser cache to test?

Comment: Thanks a lot @shariqkhan... Your answer worked for me.. Thank you so much